# Find the slope of line L

Tags: conic-sections

A straight line ($L$) passing through the point $A(1,2)$ meets the line $x+y=4$ at the point $B$. If $AB=\sqrt 2$, what is the slope of $L$?

With some help I did it and the slope comes out to be 2+√3 or 2-√3

Comment: Why is it down voted? I don't get it.

Comment: ...because you didn't try it before asking about it here.

Comment: Ok so that is why I'll note that from now on (I'm new here and I thought it was like a discussion here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B(x,y)$. You look for the slope
$$
\frac{y-2}{x-1}
$$

and $x+y = 4$, and $2 = AB^2 = (x - 1)^2 + (y-2)^2$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Done sorry for asking before solving my bad

Comment: did that help? ${}$

Comment: The method yes very much had to solve quadratic in y and that's it thanks to you

Comment: Sorry I can't see the button in the mobile site it seems but once I get into PC I'll do it. Is that fine?

Answer (score 2):

Let the coordinate of point $B$ be $(a,4-a)$

Given that $AB=\sqrt2$. Solve for $a$

Then you will get coordinate of B and you have already coordinate of A. You can get the slope very easily.